# pandas - transform dataframe column values in to rows

Tags: pandas

I have a simple question that has probably been answered before however I searched and couldn't find a working solution. So, I got a dataframe that looks like this -

```
0    Key        Key1        Key2        Key3
1    value1     value2      value3      value4
```

How could I transform it in to something like this ?

```
0    Keys_Colum        Values_Column
1    Key               value
2    Key1              value1
3    Key2              value2
4    Key3              value3
```

basically transforming a dataframe of two rows with multiple columns in to a dataframe of two columns and multiple rows.

Comment: Try `df.melt(var_name='Keys_column', value_name='Values_column')`

Comment: df = df.T doesn't do job?

Comment: Try `df.set_index(pd.np.array(['keys', 'values'])).T` but the solution is to transpose.

Answer (score 0):

A simple transpose work just fine:

```
df.T.rename(columns={
    0: 'Keys_Column',
    1: 'Values_Column'
})
```